# Click on any one of "1 2 3 4 5 ..." on a page by using Selenium in Python (e.g., Splinter):

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-webdriver, splinter

I have HTML that looks like the three following sample statements:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$FormContent$gvResults','Page$10')">...</a>

<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$FormContent$gvResults','Page$12')">12</a>

<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$FormContent$gvResults','Page$13')">13</a>
```

(I'd presently be on pg. 11.)

I don't know the Py/Selenium/Splinter syntax for selecting one of the page numbers in a list and clicking on it to go to that page.  (Also, I need to be able to identify the element in the argument as, for example, 'Page$10' or 'Page$12', as seen in the __doPostBack notation.  Maybe just a 'next page', in so many words, would be fine, but I don't even know how to do that.)

Thank you for any help.

**UPDATE II:**  Here's the code I have to work from:

```
import time
import win32ui
import win32api
import win32con
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from ctypes import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://[site]');
```

**UPDATE III:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "montpa_05.py", line 47, in <module>
    continue_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('4')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 246, in find_element_by_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 680, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
, line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'no such element\n
 (Session info: chrome=28.0.1500.95)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.2,platform=
Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<a>` element is defined as a link.  That means that you can select it by link text.

I don't know Python, but the java syntax would be `By.linkText(##)` where `##` is the number you want to click on.

Comment: MrTi, thank you for replying.  My problem is that if I'm in, say, section "... 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ..." (that's a verbatim string on the page), each of those ellipses look identical as <a> elements, yet one of them is named internally as 'Page$10' and the other as 'Page$21'.  So I can't call either specifically as just '...'.

Comment: Yes, but By.linkText works differently.  It actually is calling by the visible text, not by the inner attributes

Comment: Please see my new post.

Comment: I"m sorry, but I don't understand what you need.  Do you want to click on X page number?  Do you want to identify what page you are on?  Are you wanting to verify that the HTML attribute is there?

Comment: I want to click on X page number.  The HTML that's there looks like this:  <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$FormContent$gvResults','Page$4')">4</a>.  I've appended my code above in an update.

Comment: Link text will work.  https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text

Comment: Darn.  I just went to your link and used that statement and this is what the feedback is on the command line (in UPDATE II, above).

Comment: MrTi, thanks for this.  It works if I allow enough time for the screen to change to the one that contains this numerical sequence (I put a sleep() instruction in front of it).  Being so new to this, I didn't know how asynchronous this library is.  Thanks again.